# Multiple clicks with one click in Jquery, with selector issue

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, selector

I have a list of elements with an "add to cart" button on the left (cart installed with a Wordpress Plugin). When I click on the button that element is added to a shopping cart (no new page opened, it just shows an "added" message). 
I'd like to have a final link "add all elements to cart" which, if clicked, clicks simultaneously all "add to cart" buttons.
My PROBLEM is: i can't use a selector related to the "add to cart" button, because the add to cart button has not a unique id, just a class, which is always the same for all buttons (and I can't change it). But I managed to close the button inside a div which has a unique class attribute related to the product. So, this is the code situation for the buttons:

```
// Product 1
<div class="cart1">
    <form action="http://url" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <input class="button" value="Add to cart" title="Add product to cart" type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
// Product 2
<div class="cart2">
    <form action="http://url" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <input class="button" value="Add to cart" title="Add product to cart" type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

For the jquery code I thought that some click function would be ok, something like

```
<a onclick="functionClick1();functionClick2();">Add every product to cart</a>
```

for the html, and

```
functionClick1() {
    $("").click();
    }
```

for the javascript. But what can I put inside the quotation marks, since the add to cart button has not a unique class or id? How can I tell him: click the button contained inside the div class="cart1" element?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below jquery code

```
$("div.cart1 > input,div.cart2 > input").click(function(){alert("input inside cart1/cart2"});
```

Thanks

Comment: Silly question: just realized it would be better for me to insert this function directly inside the onclick="", but how can I write the > symbols without breaking the html?

Comment: Anyway, I tried to use it in the proper way (function placed in the head of the document and called by the onclick) and it didn't work :/